# Convertir Query SQL to Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Necesito convertir esta query a linq.

```
   select CONVERT(date, tt.FechaHora)
 , k.Numero
 ,MAX(FechaHora)
 ,MIN(FechaHora)
 ,count(case when tt.EstadoTransaccionID=1 then TransaccionID else null end)
  ,count(case when tt.EstadoTransaccionID=2 then TransaccionID else null end)
 ,(select top 1 c.Observacion from Cierre c where CONVERT(date, c.FechaHora)= CONVERT(date, tt.FechaHora)) 
 from Transaccion tt
 left join Kiosk k on k.KioskID = tt.KioskID
 where TipoTransaccionID=3
 and EstadoTransaccionID in (1,2)
 group by CONVERT(date, tt.FechaHora), k.Numero
 order by CONVERT(date, tt.FechaHora) desc;
```

Se que puedo hacerlo por stored procedure pero para no cambiar todo preferiria hacerlo con linq

al tener max min y counts con where intente hacerlo de la siguiente manera con linq:

```
                         Monitoreos = (from ticketitem in db.Transacciones
                                      where
                                      (listaATM.Count() == 0 || listaATM.Contains((int)ticketitem.KioskID))
                                      && (ticketitem.FechaHora >= FechaDesde || FechaDesde == null)
                                      && (ticketitem.FechaHora <= FechaHasta || FechaHasta == null)
                                      && (ticketitem.TipoTransaccionID == 3)
                                      && (ticketitem.EstadoTransaccionID == 1 || ticketitem.EstadoTransaccionID == 2)
                                      group ticketitem by new
                                      {
                                          date= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(ticketitem.FechaHora),
                                          numero = ticketitem.Kiosk.Numero,
                                      } into g
                                      select new MonitoreoDTO
                                      {
                                          Fecha = g.FirstOrDefault().FechaHora.ToString(),
                                          NroPos = g.FirstOrDefault().Kiosk.Numero,
                                          FechaPrimeraOperacion = g.Max(x=> x.FechaHora).ToString(),
                                          FechaUltimaOperacion = g.Min(x => x.FechaHora).ToString(),
                                          CantEfectuadas = g.Count(x=> x.EstadoTransaccionID==1),
                                          CantPendientes = g.Count(x => x.EstadoTransaccionID == 2),
                                          Observacion = db.Cierres.Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.FechaHora) == g.FirstOrDefault().FechaHora).Take(1).OrderByDescending(x => x.FechaHora).FirstOrDefault().Observacion,
                                      }).OrderByDescending(x=> x.Fecha).Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Pero nunca termina, por si se preguntan tiene un paginador en el cual toma 25 por pagina para no tener que tomar toda la lista.

Mi duda es que en SQL lo hace en 1 minuto pero es linq nunca termina siempre sale por timeout aun teniendo 30 minutos en command timeout. Realmente no se donde esta el error.

Saludos.

Comment: Que has intentado? cuál es tu duda concreta?

Comment: Ahi edite la pregunta.

Comment: Si es Entity Framewotk puedes usar: "((System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery)query)
            .ToTraceString()" donde query es tu query (objeto IQueryable) de linq.